# sql developer delete duplicates from columns from 2 tables query

Tags: sql

sql developer delete query

which will remove duplicates for **CUSTOMER** columns `ID`, `CustLastName`, `CustFirstName` and **INVOICE** columns `Invoice__Date` and `Invoice__No`.

**Column names in CUSTOMER table**: ID, DB, CUSTLASTNAME, CUSTFIRSTNAME,

**Column names in INVOICE table**: INVOICE__NO, ID, INVOICE__DATE,

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected outcome. Also, Please add a relevant database tag.

Comment: On top of that, I would also suggest to be more descriptive and not just throw some characters and SQL in there. The more you describe, the better it gets to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax in `CUSTOMER` table **ONLY** because you've not mentioned enough data from your second `INVOICE` table to at least create `FULL OUTR JOIN` between them.

**Code Syntax**

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER.ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(CUSTOMER.ID) AS MaxRecordID
        FROM CUSTOMER
        FULL OUTER JOIN INVOICE
        ON CUSTOMER.ID = INVOICE.ID
        GROUP BY CustLastName, CustFirstName
    );
```

This Syntax in terms of `FULL OUTER JOIN` should looks like this:-

[image: enter link description here]

Although I don't know how do you've duplicates values with unique `ID`?

Comment: Column names in CUSTOMER table:

ID,
DB,
CUSTLASTNAME,
CUSTFIRSTNAME,

Column names in INVOICE table:

INVOICE__NO,
ID,
INVOICE__DATE,

Comment: Do `INVOICE` table has column for `CUSTOMER.ID`?

Comment: The ID column in INVOICE is just the ID number which is also in CUSTOMER column.  if that makes sense

Comment: like in the CUSTOMER table you have custfirstname, custlastname, ID. . The ID number is linked to a customer

Comment: I will assume that the `ID` in both tables simulate the same data in both sides and i will work depend on that.

Comment: You can check it for now.

Comment: yes for example in customer table, it would be like ID:01  CUSTFIRSTNAME: JOHN | CUSTOMERLASTNAME:CITIZEN.  so customer ID:01 belongs to john citizen and ID:01 will belong to john citizen in INVOICE table

Comment: If that what's your data is about, try my Syntax and tell me what's the results and if it works.

Comment: it said 0 rows deleted.

Comment: Can you show a simple of your both tables to check my query on it?

Answer (score 0):

The below Query will just keep the top row out of all duplicates

```
delete from customer a where rowid != (select max(rowid) from customer b where a.id=b.id)
```

Similar Query can be written for any table just replacing customer and id